# Create a TypeORM ViewEntity

Tags: database, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

When I create a TypeORM ViewEntity should running a migration build it in my DB?

Also in the "Complete Example" it fails to differentiate which snippets of code are different files. I gather the first 2 are the base views, the 3rd is the ViewEntity but is the 4th a part of the 3rd, how are they related / named?

reference: https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/view-entities

Comment: Yes, the migration purpose backs to making changes to the database. It must be executed to be able to use models.

Comment: Models(tables) as separate entities could be referenced to each other.
I advise understanding databases' way of working and also how classes work in JS/TS.